# Tunneling from kubernetes to dev machine via Headless Service and Endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, networking, service, port, tunneling

I'm trying to use a `headless service` with an `endpoint` to forward traffic from within my cluster to my local development machine. I want to listen on port 80 on the service and call port 5002 on the endpoint. I have it setup as so:

Headless Service (listening on port 80 with a targetPort of 5002):
[image: kubectl describe service web]

Endpoint (pointing to my development computer on port 5002):
[image: kubectl describe endpoints web]

When I try to `curl http://web:80` from any pod in my cluster on port 80 it times out. If I `curl http://web:5002` it successfully goes through and hits my development machine. Shouldn't the `targetPort` make the request to `web:80` go to my endpoint on port `5002`?

`curl web:80`
[image: curl web]

`curl web:5002`
[image: curl web:5002]

Some additional info:

- My cluster and dev machine are in the same local network
- I'm using K3S on the cluster
- I'm just trying to emulate what Bridge For Kubernetes does

Here is the manifest yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5002
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: default
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: $HOST_IP
    ports:
      - name: web
        port: 5002
        protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work by removing the `clusterIP: None`. My manifest now looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: web
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5002
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: web
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: $HOST_IP
    ports:
      - name: web
        port: 5002
```